# Put a string in file path

Tags: java

I want to put string in the path of File as shown below:

```
 String type="videos";
 File folder = new File("C:\\Program Files\\Apache Software Foundation\\Tomcat 6.0\\webapps\\book\\+type") ;
```

It is giving *null pointer exception*.

Please tell to me how to put a string in the path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the `"` from around `type`:

```
("C:\\Program Files\\Apache Software Foundation\\Tomcat 6.0\\webapps\\book\\" + type);
                                                                               ↑
```

Try the following:

```
String str = "World";
System.out.println("Hello " + str);
```

Read the [official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) to better understand Strings.

You're getting [`NullPointerException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html) because the file `"type"` doesn't exist, so `folder` will be `null`, and if you don't check if it's `null`, you'll get the exception when you try to do `folder.something`.

Answer (score 0):

```
File folder = new File("C:\\Program Files\\Apache Software Foundation\\Tomcat 6.0\\webapps\\book\\" + type);
```